# Filtering with variable time interval using dplyr

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I want to filter my time series based on a variable time interval. More specifically, consider the time *t_i* from a timestamp *t*. I want to filter my time series such that what remains is a time series containing only timestamps from *t_i* - 15 min up to and including *t_i* + 15 min.

Here's what I tried:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

mv <- 2 # moving window
t <- as.POSIXct("2020-06-20 12:00", tz="UTC") # time stamp
time <- seq(ymd_hm('2020-01-01 00:00'),ymd_hm('2020-12-31 23:45'), by = '15 mins')
ts <- tibble(time=time, data=sin(seq(1,length(time),1)))

# What I did:
ts %>%
  filter(time >= t - mv*24*60*60) %>%
  filter(time <= t) %>%
  filter(strftime(time, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC") >= strftime(t-15*60, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC")) %>%
  filter(strftime(time, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC") <= strftime(t+15*60, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC"))

Output:

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  time                   data
  <dttm>                <dbl>
1 2020-06-18 12:00:00 -0.435 
2 2020-06-18 12:15:00  0.523 
3 2020-06-19 11:45:00  0.298 
4 2020-06-19 12:00:00  0.964 
5 2020-06-19 12:15:00  0.744 
6 2020-06-20 11:45:00  0.885 
7 2020-06-20 12:00:00  0.0870
```

This is exactly what I want but it breaks down when `t <- as.POSIXct("2020-06-20 23:45", tz="UTC")` (also with `00:00`):

```
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# … with 2 variables: time <dttm>, data <dbl>
```

I included an if-else statement to circumvent this but it is far from elegant and doesn't give me exactly what I want:

```
t <- as.POSIXct("2020-06-20 23:45", tz="UTC") # time stamp
if(strftime(t, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC") %in% c("23:45","00:00")){
  ts %>% 
    filter(time >= t - mv*24*60*60) %>%
    filter(time <= t) %>%
    filter(strftime(time, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC") >= strftime(t-15*60, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC"))
} else {
  ts %>% 
    filter(time >= t - mv*24*60*60) %>%
    filter(time <= t) %>%
    filter(strftime(time, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC") >= strftime(t-15*60, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC")) %>%
    filter(strftime(time, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC") <= strftime(t+15*60, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC"))
}

Output:
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  time                  data
  <dttm>               <dbl>
1 2020-06-18 23:45:00  0.543
2 2020-06-19 23:30:00 -0.177
3 2020-06-19 23:45:00 -0.924
4 2020-06-20 23:30:00 -0.936
5 2020-06-20 23:45:00 -0.209

Desired output:
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  time                  data
  <dttm>               <dbl>
1 2020-06-18 23:45:00  0.543
2 2020-06-19 00:00:00 -0.413
3 2020-06-19 23:30:00 -0.177
4 2020-06-19 23:45:00 -0.924
5 2020-06-20 00:00:00 -0.821
6 2020-06-20 23:30:00 -0.936
7 2020-06-20 23:45:00 -0.209
```

There seems to be an issue with the shift between days but I'm not sure how to solve it and I haven't been able to find similar questions. Is there a way to achieve this (elegantly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It apperars that `strftime(ts$time[1], format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC")  > strftime(t, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC")` is evaluated to `FALSE` which makes sense depending on how you look at it.

To mitigate this you'll need full `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` such that it is evaluated 'correctly'. Which will be the case if you evaluate the the full string, instead of only the `hours`.

We can get the `intervals` by adding a `dummy`-variable we call `time_` that includes all the `HH:MM`, and then treat them as `strings`,

```
# Troublesome Vector;
t <- ymd_hm("2020-06-20 23:45", tz="UTC")




ts %>% filter(
        between(
                time, 
                left = t - mv*24*60*60 -15*60,
                right = t
        )
) %>% mutate(
        time_ = strftime(time, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC") %>% as.character()
) %>% filter(
        str_detect(
                time_,
                pattern = seq(
                        t-15*60,
                        t+15*60,
                        by = "15 mins"
                ) %>% strftime(format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC") %>% paste(
                        collapse = "|"
                )
        )
)
```

Which gives the `output`,

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  time                  data time_
  <dttm>               <dbl> <chr>
1 2020-06-18 23:30:00  1.00  23:30
2 2020-06-18 23:45:00  0.543 23:45
3 2020-06-19 00:00:00 -0.413 00:00
4 2020-06-19 23:30:00 -0.177 23:30
5 2020-06-19 23:45:00 -0.924 23:45
6 2020-06-20 00:00:00 -0.821 00:00
7 2020-06-20 23:30:00 -0.936 23:30
8 2020-06-20 23:45:00 -0.209 23:45
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not what I'm after. I want to get a tibble of 7 rows as per my example. In your case, it seems to be a continuous time series from `2020-06-18 23:30:00` whereas I'm looking for half hour intervals around the time of timestamp *t* (i.e., `23:45`) on a select number of preceding days.

Comment: Ah - I see, the desired output got blurred away for me. Give me a minute or two! :-)

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I know it is not pretty to look at, but its a start! :-)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick! Can you just explain the last part (`paste(collapse = "|")`)? I noticed that when I remove it, it returns the same result but with a warning message: `In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: This is because when you `paste(collapse = "|")` it transforms the vector to a `character` that looks like `"A|B|C"` that such that when you do `str_detect()` it looks for strings containing A or B or C!

Comment: **NOTE:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68480540/how-to-make-custom-function-in-tidyverse-more-readable/68480555#68480555 - if you want to make it a as a function if your inputs vary!

Answer (score 1):

```
ts %>%
  filter(between(time, t - days(mv), t)) %>%
  mutate(aux = as.numeric(time) %% (60 * 60 * 24)) %>%
  filter(between(aux,
                 (as.numeric(t) %% (60 * 60 * 24) - 900),
                 (as.numeric(t) %% (60 * 60 * 24) + 900)) |
           aux == 0) %>%
  select(-aux)
```

gives

```
   # # A tibble: 7 x 2
   #   time                  data
   #   <dttm>               <dbl>
   # 1 2020-06-18 23:45:00  0.543
   # 2 2020-06-19 00:00:00 -0.413
   # 3 2020-06-19 23:30:00 -0.177
   # 4 2020-06-19 23:45:00 -0.924
   # 5 2020-06-20 00:00:00 -0.821
   # 6 2020-06-20 23:30:00 -0.936
   # 7 2020-06-20 23:45:00 -0.209
```

It's probably very particular for this specific task and a bit hard to read. The interval reflects a duration (fixed amount of seconds).
For similar cases, where the date increases, you need to change the offsets and adjust the values by 86400. This version doesn't work if `t` is as midnight nor if the offset is not equal to 15'.

If you have just 2 days, this would also be an approach (using periods instead of durations):

```
ts %>%
  filter(between(time, t - days(mv), t)) %>%
  filter(between(time, t - minutes(15), t + minutes(15)) |
         between(time, t - days(1) - minutes(15), t - days(1) + minutes(15)) | 
         between(time, t - days(2) - minutes(15), t - days(2) + minutes(15)))
```

which gives the same result in this case.
If you want to adjust the margins, you need to change the values.

By the way: you should NOT use `t` as name for an object in R, because it's already the name of a function.

HTH